# How create a TreeTable in DebugSession

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, treeview, intellij-plugin

I'm looking for a way to create a TreeTable in intellij Plugin.
The Tab in the DebugSession can I create in *com.intellij.xdebugger.XDebugProcess#createTabLayouter*, but I cant' create a TreeTable inside that JPanel.

My View looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <form xmlns="http://www.intellij.com/uidesigner/form/" version="1" bind-to-class="debugger.ui.RegisterViewSessionTab">
      <grid id="27dc6" binding="content" layout-manager="GridLayoutManager" row-count="1" column-count="1" same-size-horizontally="false" same-size-vertically="false" hgap="-1" vgap="-1">
        <margin top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0"/>
        <constraints>
          <xy x="20" y="20" width="500" height="400"/>
        </constraints>
        <properties/>
        <border type="none"/>
        <children>
          <scrollpane id="86eac">
            <constraints>
              <grid row="0" column="0" row-span="1" col-span="1" vsize-policy="7" hsize-policy="7" anchor="0" fill="3" indent="0" use-parent-layout="false"/>
            </constraints>
            <properties/>
            <border type="none"/>
            <children>
              <component id="8217" class="com.intellij.ui.treeStructure.treetable.TreeTable" binding="tree" custom-create="true">
                <constraints/>
                <properties/>
              </component>
            </children>
          </scrollpane>
        </children>
      </grid>
    </form>
```

And the code behinde (RegisterViewSessionTab):

```
    pc = new DefaultRegisterNode();
    sp = new DefaultRegisterNode();
    DefaultRegisterNode group = new DefaultRegisterNode();

    group.setName("Core Registers");
    group.setDescription("Core Registers");
    group.setValue("");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(group);

    pc.setName("PC");
    pc.setDescription("Program Counter [Core]");
    pc.setValue("---");
    DefaultMutableTreeNode nodePc = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(pc);
    root.add(nodePc);

    sp.setName("SP");
    sp.setDescription("Stack Pointer [Core]");
    sp.setValue("---");

    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(sp);
    root.add(node);

    ColumnInfo[] columnInfos = new ColumnInfo[3];
    columnInfos[0] = new ColumnInfo<DefaultMutableTreeNode, String>("Name") {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String valueOf(DefaultMutableTreeNode defaultRegisterNode) {
            return ((DefaultRegisterNode)defaultRegisterNode.getUserObject()).getName();
        }
    };
    columnInfos[1] = new TableModelEditor.EditableColumnInfo<DefaultMutableTreeNode, String>("Value") {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String valueOf(DefaultMutableTreeNode defaultRegisterNode) {
            return ((DefaultRegisterNode)defaultRegisterNode.getUserObject()).getValue();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public TableCellEditor getEditor(DefaultMutableTreeNode defaultRegisterNode) {
            return new StringTableCellEditor(project);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(DefaultMutableTreeNode defaultRegisterNode, String value) {
            ((DefaultRegisterNode)defaultRegisterNode.getUserObject()).setValue(value);
        }
    };
    columnInfos[2] = new ColumnInfo<DefaultMutableTreeNode, String>("Description") {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public String valueOf(DefaultMutableTreeNode defaultRegisterNode) {
            return ((DefaultRegisterNode)defaultRegisterNode.getUserObject()).getDescription();
        }
    };

    ListTreeTableModelOnColumns registersModel = new ListTreeTableModelOnColumns(root, columnInfos);
    tree = new TreeTable(registersModel);
```

Model class:

```
public class DefaultRegisterNode {
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String value;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

In action:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxGQH.png

But there isn't a collapsed/expanded button? How can I enable this feature in the TreeTable?

If you need something more, please contact me!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a TreeTableView the root node will show also. But the error isn't there. I found it.

```
ColumnInfo[] columnInfos = new ColumnInfo[] {
    new TreeColumnInfo("Name"),   // <-- This is important!
    new ColumnInfo<Node, String>("Name S1") {
       ...
    }
};
```

Add a TreeColumnInfo to the ColumnInfos above. This will add the Expand/Collapse Arrows. Now you must create a TreeCellRenderer and set to the Tree.

```
public static class Tree extends TreeTableView {

    public Tree(ListTreeTableModelOnColumns treeTableModel) {
        super(treeTableModel);

        setTreeCellRenderer(new Renderer());
    }

    class Renderer extends ColoredTreeCellRenderer  {
        @Override
        public void customizeCellRenderer(@NotNull JTree tree, Object value, boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {
            Node node = (Node)value;
            NodeModel model = node.getUserObject();

            append(model.Name);
        }

    }
}
```